# Inserting element in binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures

The code is for inserting an element in a binary tree using level order traversal. I'll first tell u how it works. It first goes through the nodes in each level and if there is any node which doesn't have both children it inserts the node as a child to that node and it use's queue for storing and retrieving the nodes addresses. My problem is that every time I call the create function the root value which is passed is always null even after inserting a node the root value is not changed and it's still a null. I am unable to figure out what's wrong in this. Can anyone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
   struct node *left,*right;
}*root;

struct queue
{
   int capacity,rear,front;
   struct node **qu;
};


void enqueue(struct queue *q,struct node *n)
{
   q->front=(++(q->front))%q->capacity;
   (q->qu)[q->front]=n;
   if(q->rear==-1)
   q->rear++;
}

struct node* dequeue(struct queue *q)
{
   struct node *temp;
   temp=q->qu[q->rear];
   if(q->front==q->rear)
   q->front=q->rear=-1;
   else
   q->rear=(++(q->rear))%q->capacity;
}

int isempty(struct queue *q)
{
   return(q->rear==-1);
}

struct queue* create(unsigned int capacity)
{
   struct queue *p;
   p=(struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
   p->capacity=capacity;
   p->front=p->rear=-1;
   p->qu=(struct node**)malloc(sizeof(struct node)*capacity);
   return p;
}


 void insert(struct node *root)
 {
    int n;
    struct node *p,*q;
    struct queue *tmp;
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->left=p->right=NULL;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p->data=n;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
      root=p;
      return;
    }
    tmp=create(20);
    enqueue(tmp,root);
    while(isempty(tmp))
    {
      q=dequeue(tmp);
      printf("%d %d\n",p,root);
      if((!q->right)||(!q->left))
      {
          if(!q->right)
          q->right=p;
          else
          q->left=p;
          return;
      }
      else
      {
         enqueue(tmp,q->left);
         enqueue(tmp,q->right);
      }
    }
 }

 void traverse(struct node *root)
 {
   if(!root)
   return;
   traverse(root->left);
   printf("%d ",root->data);
   traverse(root->right);
 }

void main()
{
   int i,n;
   while(1)
   {
       printf("1.insert\n2.exit\n");
       scanf("%d",&n);
       switch(n)
       {
          case 2:goto end;
          case 1:insert(root);
       }
    }
    end:
    traverse(root);
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's a lot of code that is not for inserting an element into a binary tree.

Comment: yeah i just want to make it clear about the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `root` as a global variable, but your insert function also defines it's own local version of `root` which takes precedence. Because you're passing `root` in by value rather than reference, changing it's value has no effect. You have two options on how to fix this.

- Pass `root` by reference

You change insert to be `void insert(struct node **root)` and then replace all instances of `root` in the function with `(*root)`. You'll also need to pass a pointer to root when you call it - `insert(&root)`

- Return the new value of `root`

Change the return type to `struct node *` and make sure you `return root` at the end and at any point where you're already returning from the function. When you call it you'll assign the return value to `root` like `root=insert(root)`

Both are equally valid options.

Comment: the tree is not getting traversed if i use root only as the global variable and iam not passing any value to insert method the tree is getting traversed only  for the first node.

Comment: you are passing a value to insert - see this line: `case 1:insert(root);` - that's passing `root` by value. Maybe this explains the difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: Also, `root` doesn't need to be global - it'd be better if it were declared locally in `main`